# How to run a function once in life and other function on daily basis in python using Airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have two functions in my python script 1:get_all_invoices() this function download all the invoices from the stripe and 2nd:get_daily_invoices() which download only today's invoices So I want to run function 1:get_all_invoices() only once in DAG life and 2nd-function:get_daily_invoices() on daily bases.
What could be the possible solution whether I have to manage this in python script or need to manage in Airflow DAG.
My code:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    start_date=START_DATE,
    max_active_runs=MAX_ACTIVE_RUN,
    catchup=False,
    default_args=default_args,
    concurrency=MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS

)
latest_only = LatestOnlyOperator(task_id='my_latest_only', dag=dag)
stripetos3_scheduler = DockerOperator(
    task_id='stripe-to-s3',
    image='registry.gitlab.com/mobinalhassan/stripetos3dags:latest',
    auto_remove=True,
    force_pull=True,
    dag=dag
)
latest_only >> stripetos3_scheduler
```

Comment: Wheere is `get_daily_invoices()`  and `get_all_invoices()`  in your code?

Comment: As far as I can see it, you have two options.

Comment: @MenyIssakov Yes please tell me...

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand if you want to run the first function just once entirely, or if there will be another time you might want to run it.

the first option, would be to separate the two functions into 2 different dags, one with the daily schedule and one without a schedule (and trigger manually or via API).

Another option is to hold a flag for internal state (DB/file, wherever..) so the first function will skip the execution if the flag was already set